# Why does my page keep returning to the top?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a submit button once it is clicked. The button gets hidden but for some reason the page keeps shooting back up to the top. Here is a portion of my jquery. What have I gotten wrong? Thanks.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', '.results', function(e) {
                 var btn = $(this).find("button"); //Find button clicked

                 $(btn).hide(); //Hide button on click

                 e.preventDefault();
```

The html

```
<!---ADD TO TABLE FORM----->
  <form id="myForm'.$i.'" class="myForm" action="" method="post" style="">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="file" value="'.$file.'">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="'.$_SESSION["user_name"].'">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$_SESSION["user_session"].'">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="'.$id.'">

<span class="pull-right">


<button type="submit" class="fabutton">

<i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too? Does your form action point to a different page or the same? Does your form have the class `myForm`? If your form does have that class name, then this code should work. Technically you already have a jQuery object for btn, so you don't need to wrap it, but the other code is fine. Here's a working version with everything you pasted: https://jsfiddle.net/rvssxz2s/ (try scrolling down, then click the button, and you'll notice the page doesn't scroll)

Comment: please post the html also

Comment: It sounds like you may be clicking on an `<a />` tag & adding a `#` to the url which is moving the screen back to the top!

Comment: is the issue when you click this button `<button type="submit" class="fabutton">` ??

Comment: I think I've figured it out. The script does work but I also have a modal popping up when the button is clicked. Once this modal is closed the screen is scrolling to the top so I guess the issue lies with the modal and not this code. Thanks for the help.